# Max condition for a char datatype column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have a table with char datatype for a column. Need to fetch max number from that column.

some values in that column are 1,2,3,A,B

while fetching max(column) I only get the char - 'B', how do i get the max among numeric value?
    `select max(cast(floor as int)) from floormaster`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  MAX(CAST(columnName AS INT)) MAX_VALUE
FROM    tableName
WHERE   ISNUMERIC(columnName) = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13bca/3)
- [ISNUMERIC()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)